# Diagnosing why S3 retrieval is so slow

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, airflow, boto3

I am using an S3 Hook in Airflow to retrieve a large list of keys from an S3 bucket.
In real life I will be getting the list of keys from a database query, but for this example I am simply listing all the keys in the bucket, iterating, and retrieving.

It is taking around 100ms per file, and often much longer.

Each file is only around 500 bytes.

My Dag looks like this

```
# We'll start by importing the DAG object
from airflow import DAG
# We need to import the operators used in our tasks
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
# Import variables
from airflow.models import Variable
# We then import the days_ago function
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import timedelta, datetime
import json, os, logging
from http.client import HTTPConnection # py3
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.hooks.s3 import S3Hook
import urllib3

# initializing the default arguments that we'll pass to our DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 4, 10),
    'email': ['test@test.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 1,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'execution_timeout': timedelta(hours=1),
}

def fetch_s3_object(source_s3, bucket_name, s3_key):
    print(f"Fetching {s3_key} from {bucket_name}")
    return source_s3.get_key(s3_key, bucket_name)

def s3_list_objects(source_s3, bucket_name,):
    print(f"Listing keys in {bucket_name}")
    return source_s3.list_keys(bucket_name)

def download_from_s3():
    s3_hook = S3Hook('aws_tds')
    bucket_name = 'dc4h-trust-a-pas-staging'

    # List all Objects in S3
    start_time = datetime.now()
    s3_keys = s3_list_objects(s3_hook, bucket_name)
    print(f"The number of keys in bucket: {len(s3_keys)}, time taken (ms): {int((datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds() * 1000)}")

    for s3_object_key in s3_keys:
        start_time = datetime.now()
        s3_object = fetch_s3_object(s3_hook, bucket_name, s3_object_key )
        print(f"Getting key {s3_object_key} took {int((datetime.now() - start_time).total_seconds() * 1000)}ms")

process_test_download = DAG(
    dag_id=f"DC4H_S3_Download_Test",
    default_args=default_args,
    description=f"Test Downloading From S3",
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False
)

task_1 = PythonOperator(
    task_id='query_staging_and_download',
    python_callable=download_from_s3,
    dag=process_test_download,
)
```

When executing, the log shows the times:

```
[2023-04-12, 19:01:11 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Listing keys in test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:11 UTC] {base.py:68} INFO - Using connection ID 'aws_tds' for task execution.
[2023-04-12, 19:01:11 UTC] {connection_wrapper.py:210} INFO - AWS Connection (conn_id='aws_tds', conn_type='aws') credentials retrieved from login and password.
[2023-04-12, 19:01:11 UTC] {connection_wrapper.py:132} INFO - Retrieving region_name=eu-west-3 from AWS Connection (conn_id='aws_tds', conn_type='aws') extra.
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - The number of keys in bucket: 1224, time taken (ms): 388
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 009f533b-312e-4fb7-89d7-4726d77f3ff4 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 009f533b-312e-4fb7-89d7-4726d77f3ff4 took 304ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 00c6203f-9a55-4c79-9b5e-1494bbee7612 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 00c6203f-9a55-4c79-9b5e-1494bbee7612 took 119ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 01179ef8-4827-4b0d-99fe-efd21bd6ebd6 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 01179ef8-4827-4b0d-99fe-efd21bd6ebd6 took 108ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 013025f5-cd96-480c-9b3c-4570f85ddbbe from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 013025f5-cd96-480c-9b3c-4570f85ddbbe took 100ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 015e0d47-d2be-4038-891f-a27dce63bf57 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 015e0d47-d2be-4038-891f-a27dce63bf57 took 99ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:12 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 0166d63b-d7d1-4bd9-9c36-1d8b8d59bfd6 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 0166d63b-d7d1-4bd9-9c36-1d8b8d59bfd6 took 288ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 016939f4-e7cb-4bf5-bfcd-54d4945bfc69 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 016939f4-e7cb-4bf5-bfcd-54d4945bfc69 took 100ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 016f9ac4-25a2-403b-a2b7-cad23780b4d4 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 016f9ac4-25a2-403b-a2b7-cad23780b4d4 took 87ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 01e65355-6744-4e0b-80c0-243632341613 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 01e65355-6744-4e0b-80c0-243632341613 took 90ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 01f6dbc0-22e3-4686-94ef-deeebe94efba from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 01f6dbc0-22e3-4686-94ef-deeebe94efba took 87ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 02189147-e400-4208-becc-99abd80106d2 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 02189147-e400-4208-becc-99abd80106d2 took 278ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 021fdd77-3cc2-4143-94e4-f1c7aca3d27c from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 021fdd77-3cc2-4143-94e4-f1c7aca3d27c took 99ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 0229a75c-1cad-4a97-ac95-66ca282f4cb5 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 0229a75c-1cad-4a97-ac95-66ca282f4cb5 took 89ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:13 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 0231a7ed-8a07-40d0-b69f-4ae4d835df22 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 0231a7ed-8a07-40d0-b69f-4ae4d835df22 took 128ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 028aa23a-4e90-40e3-ba29-d5aa44d1e60a from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 028aa23a-4e90-40e3-ba29-d5aa44d1e60a took 103ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 0291dc17-7233-4b46-a3cb-c4fdba21d822 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 0291dc17-7233-4b46-a3cb-c4fdba21d822 took 293ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 02b5fd32-2cf1-4137-b3f1-0fd4691f7492 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 02b5fd32-2cf1-4137-b3f1-0fd4691f7492 took 94ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 0304ae1a-2472-465e-93b5-d5dc5d9bfbfb from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 0304ae1a-2472-465e-93b5-d5dc5d9bfbfb took 94ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 030a06bb-efe5-4df8-911d-2cf627b8f4bf from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 030a06bb-efe5-4df8-911d-2cf627b8f4bf took 112ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 0328e001-8476-4860-ace3-4f5e1ca04b48 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 0328e001-8476-4860-ace3-4f5e1ca04b48 took 115ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:14 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 032a0476-17e5-4d5c-a944-945b2989f00d from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 032a0476-17e5-4d5c-a944-945b2989f00d took 291ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 033d8174-a7ad-40da-b657-fcdc35b89737 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 033d8174-a7ad-40da-b657-fcdc35b89737 took 78ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 03675e0c-06eb-4225-a7ba-e191746d0028 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 03675e0c-06eb-4225-a7ba-e191746d0028 took 103ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 0367a9d7-0f12-4323-8cdc-7f6925148178 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 0367a9d7-0f12-4323-8cdc-7f6925148178 took 122ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 03c4bb4f-bce0-4f1b-8d39-836a68ed8c7b from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 03c4bb4f-bce0-4f1b-8d39-836a68ed8c7b took 96ms
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Fetching 03d3b0c1-07f8-4540-a71c-726686683ac6 from test-bucket
[2023-04-12, 19:01:15 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:115} INFO - Getting key 03d3b0c1-07f8-4540-a71c-726686683ac6 took 292ms
```

I am looking for a very high throughput (I have read S3 can support thousands per second?) but I am nowhere near this speed.

Unfortunately, we need to work with key-by-key retrieval given our workflow.
I have tried to multithread the downloads but that just seems to slow the individual downloads down.

I am executing from Airflow inside an EKS cluster in the same region.

Any ideas would be appreciated.